# Struts Action class execute() method…return null

Tags: plugins, struts2, struts, struts1

Struts Action class execute() method…return null

I am working on "Struts 1 Plugin".

We have a Struts1 application and we want to use Action,ActionForm of Struts1 application to into Struts 2 Application.

In Struts 1 Plugin, all Action class is getting called from Struts1Action class.

> ```
>  public class Abc extends Action
>     {
>             public ActionForward execute(mapping, form, request, response)
>             {
>                 if(some conditon)
>                 {
>                     response.sendRedirect("/some/action.do");
>                     return null;
>                 }
>             }
>     }
> ```

the above code works fine in "Struts 1" but when I try with "Struts 1 Plugin" throwing me an error.

> org.apache.catalina.core.StandradWrapperValve invoke SERVER:
>   Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException at ResponseFacade.sendError(java:
>   704); at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendError(java:108);

Reason is in `Struts1Action` class,

```
if (forward instanceof WrapperActionForward ||
actionConfig.getResults().containsKey(forward.getName())) {
```

Above line throw error.

Questions from comments, with answers:

> Is it legal to return `null` from your current context?

Yes it is legal to return `null`.

> Is `forward` really an instance of `WrapperActionForward`?

Yes `Forward` is an instance of `WrapperActionForward`.

> Or, is `actionConfig.getResults().containsKey(forward.getName())` `true`? What does `forward.getName()` return?

When `forward` is `null`, `actionConfig.getResults().containsKey(forward.getName())` will throw a Null Pointer Exception.

Here is the Stack Trace:

```
Feb 21, 2012 4:21:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:407)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendError(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:108)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.sendError(Dispatcher.java:839)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:533)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.eee.DisableUrlJSessionIdFilter.doFilter(DisableUrlJSessionIdFilter.java:65)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.eee.SetUIComponentsFilter.doFilter(SetUIComponentsFilter.java:390)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.eee.CrossSiteScriptingFilter.doFilter(CrossSiteScriptingFilter.java:44)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.eee.PerformanceFilter.doFilter(PerformanceFilter.java:66)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.eee.AppContextFilter.doFilter(AppContextFilter.java:61)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.eee.ProfileFilter.doFilter(ProfileFilter.java:56)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:264)
at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107)
at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:72)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:110)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:217)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
at org.acegisecurity.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:81)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:229)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:148)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Hi Umesh Awasthi...
Please help if you have any solution

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem? I see an exception (yay for that), but it was obviously re-typed rather than copy and pasted (please copy and paste). Is it legal to return `null` from your current context? Is `forward` really an instance of `WrapperActionForward`? Or, is `actionConfig.getResults().containsKey(forward.getName())` `true`? What does `forward.getName()` return? What does `actionConfig.getResults()` return?

Comment: The simulation steps are simple
1. Create Struts1 Application.
2. Write Action class which return null
3. Download Struts2 jar, use Struts1 plugin jar struts2-struts1-plugin-2.3.1.2.jar
4. Make simple Struts2 Jsp which uses Struts 2 tags.
5. Run the Application

Comment: I think its a bug in struts2-struts1-plugin-2.3.1.2.jar only.
File name is **Struts1Action.java** but i don't know how to solve this